# Notification Icons missing after logging out [Not Solved but overcome]

Tags: unity, 16.04, icons, notification

**strong text**On Monday Evening I updated my Desktop and Laptop and both machine have since lost the Notification Icons on the top right hand panel of Log In Screen.

It is only the "Log In/Shutdown Screen" after Logging Out of my desktop account.

I have researched this issue and NOT found a solution so far.

I'm unable post images on this site, I have included the URL address to my own google sites account, hopefully these pictures may give you a clearer idea to what is wrong or gone wrong?

Thank you in advance for your help.

******** Unistalled Unity Desktop and Install Xubuntu Desktop  *********

As there was no reply to this issue, instead of a fresh install I added Xubuntu desktop then stripped out the unity desktop following this guide: https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/alternative

Comment: If you'd like I'll edit your post to include the images.

Comment: Thank you Android Dev, how is that possible as I don't have an Imgar account?

Comment: You don't need one. You probably can't post images because you don't have many reputation points.